# Python - Running through the same code block in a loop for different variable

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have this below set of code where I perform some manipulation based after pulling some data from a source Dataframe called `df`.

```
Customer_data = []


for i in range(0, len(df)):
    try:
        Customer = (re.search(r'(Customer"=>).*?(,)', df[i]).group(0).split('=>')[1].replace('"','').replace(',',''))
    except:
        Customer = ''
    
    Customer_data.append(Customer)

Customer = pd.DataFrame(Customer_data.append, columns = ['Customer'])
```

I am trying to have the above code repeated for set of variables wherein I would replace the variable `Customer` with another variable. How could I generalise the above code such that it could be reused for other variables as well in a loop.

Example variables : `Product`, `ModelName`

Comment: If the only use of `i` in your `range(0, len(df))` is `df[i]`, you really should simply loop over `df`, like `for i in df:` and use `i` in place of `df[i]`.

Comment: Inside the regex, are you missing by change a `"` before `Customer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the regex as a string, adding there the column name from a variable. Finally passing that regex expression to `re.search`:

```
col_name = "Customer"
my_regex = r"('+re.escape(col_name)+'=>).*?(,)"

Customer_data = []

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    try:
        Customer = (re.search(my_regex, df[i]).group(0).split('=>')[1].replace('"','').replace(',',''))
    except:
        Customer = ''
    
    Customer_data.append(Customer)

Customer = pd.DataFrame(Customer_data.append, columns = ['Customer'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it inside the function, where you pass the name string of your variable (as seen in DataFrame).
Just change search part to include correct name `r'({}"=>).*?(,)'.format(name)`.

```
def my_func(df, name):
    Customer_data = []    

    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        try:
            Customer = (re.search(r'({}"=>).*?(,)'.format(name), df[i]).group(0).split('=>')[1].replace('"','').replace(',',''))
        except:
            Customer = ''
    
        Customer_data.append(Customer)

    Customer = pd.DataFrame(Customer_data.append, columns = ['Customer'])

    return Customer 

# run function 
Product = my_func(df, 'Product')
ModelName= my_func(df, 'ModelName')
```